# JodaTime show weeks in duration

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, duration

I am trying to display the difference in time between two DateTimes in the following format:

`? years, ? months, ? weeks, ? days, ? hours, ? minutes, ? seconds and ? milliseconds`

I've got it displaying almost like this, however it does not display the weeks. I have tried using PeriodType.standard(), but that omits months and years. Is it possible to do this?

Here is the code I am using to achieve the current result:

```
private String getPeriodBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to, boolean showMilliseconds) {
    Period period;

    if (from.isAfter(to)) {
        period = new Period(to, from);
    } else {
        period = new Period(from, to);
    }

    PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendYears()
        .appendSuffix(" year, ", " years, ")
        .appendMonths()
        .appendSuffix(" month, ", " months, ")
        .appendWeeks()
        .appendSuffix(" week, ", " weeks, ")
        .appendDays()
        .appendSuffix(" day, ", " days, ")
        .appendHours()
        .appendSuffix(" hour, ", " hours, ")
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendSuffix(" minute, ", " minutes, ")
        .appendSeconds()
        .appendSuffix(" second, ", " seconds, ");

    if (showMilliseconds) {
        builder = builder.appendMillis().appendSuffix(" millisecond", " milliseconds");
    }

    return builder.toFormatter()
        .print(period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime()))
        .replaceAll("[,]\\s*$", "")
        .replaceAll("(?:,\\s*)([^,]+)$", " and $1")
        .replaceAll("^(?![\\s\\S])", "No difference");
}
```

If I use `PeriodType.forFields();` and specify an array of `DurationFieldType` containing all required fields, it omits year and month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Figured it out. The problem was that I was originally using `Duration` and converting it to a `Period`. I had tried to use the following code to fix it, but it didn't give me the result I expected. After I changed it to `Period`, I could specify all of the fields I required using `Period.forFields();`, accepting the following:</strike>

```
private static final DurationFieldType[] DURATION_FIELD_TYPES = {
    DurationFieldType.years(),
    DurationFieldType.months(),
    DurationFieldType.weeks(),
    DurationFieldType.days(),
    DurationFieldType.hours(),
    DurationFieldType.minutes(),
    DurationFieldType.seconds(),
    DurationFieldType.millis(),
};
```

Never mind, you don't even need to normalise the standard as it already includes all fields by default. Now that I think about it, it makes sense. Here's my complete working code for reference:

```
private String getDifference(DateTime from, DateTime to, boolean showMilliseconds) {
    Period period;

    if (from.isAfter(to)) {
        period = new Period(to, from);
    } else {
        period = new Period(from, to);
    }

    PeriodFormatterBuilder builder = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendYears()
        .appendSuffix(" year, ", " years, ")
        .appendMonths()
        .appendSuffix(" month, ", " months, ")
        .appendWeeks()
        .appendSuffix(" week, ", " weeks, ")
        .appendDays()
        .appendSuffix(" day, ", " days, ")
        .appendHours()
        .appendSuffix(" hour, ", " hours, ")
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendSuffix(" minute, ", " minutes, ")
        .appendSeconds()
        .appendSuffix(" second, ", " seconds, ");

    if (showMilliseconds) {
        builder = builder.appendMillis().appendSuffix(" millisecond", " milliseconds");
    }

    return builder
        .toFormatter()
        .print(period)
        .replaceAll("[,]\\s*$", "")
        .replaceAll("(?:,\\s*)([^,]+)$", " and $1")
        .replaceAll("^(?![\\s\\S])", "No difference");
}
```